# How to add options to lucky Spin wheel code

Tags: javascript

I need a spinning wheel js code with these options:

- variable number of slots which should be called from another form (I want to run it in Confluence and integrate it with Confiforms)
- different chances or weight for each slot. But in view mode, slot sizes must be equal.
- users can't run it more than one time.
- I want to send its result to another form (Confiforsm).
  Also I want to put JS codes in body of site not in header.

**This is the code I've used:**

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex],
      array[currentIndex],
    ];
  }

  return array;
}

function spin() {
  // Play the sound
  wheel.play();
  // Inisialisasi variabel
  const box = document.getElementById("box");
  const element = document.getElementById("mainbox");
  let SelectedItem = "";

  // Shuffle 450 karena class box1 sudah ditambah 90 derajat diawal. minus 40 per item agar posisi panah pas ditengah.
  // Setiap item memiliki 12.5% kemenangan kecuali item sepeda yang hanya memiliki sekitar 4% peluang untuk menang.
  // Item berupa ipad dan samsung tab tidak akan pernah menang.
  // let Sepeda = shuffle([2210]); //Kemungkinan : 33% atau 1/3
  let MagicRoaster = shuffle([1890, 2250, 2610]);
  let Sepeda = shuffle([1850, 2210, 2570]); //Kemungkinan : 100%
  let RiceCooker = shuffle([1810, 2170, 2530]);
  let LunchBox = shuffle([1770, 2130, 2490]);
  let Sanken = shuffle([1750, 2110, 2470]);
  let Electrolux = shuffle([1630, 1990, 2350]);
  let JblSpeaker = shuffle([1570, 1930, 2290]);

  // Bentuk acak
  let Hasil = shuffle([
    MagicRoaster[0],
    Sepeda[0],
    RiceCooker[0],
    LunchBox[0],
    Sanken[0],
    Electrolux[0],
    JblSpeaker[0],
  ]);
  // console.log(Hasil[0]);

  // Ambil value item yang terpilih
  if (MagicRoaster.includes(Hasil[0])) SelectedItem = "Magic Roaster";
  if (Sepeda.includes(Hasil[0])) SelectedItem = "Sepeda Aviator";
  if (RiceCooker.includes(Hasil[0])) SelectedItem = "Rice Cooker Philips";
  if (LunchBox.includes(Hasil[0])) SelectedItem = "Lunch Box Lock&Lock";
  if (Sanken.includes(Hasil[0])) SelectedItem = "Air Cooler Sanken";
  if (Electrolux.includes(Hasil[0])) SelectedItem = "Electrolux Blender";
  if (JblSpeaker.includes(Hasil[0])) SelectedItem = "JBL Speaker";

  // Proses
  box.style.setProperty("transition", "all ease 5s");
  box.style.transform = "rotate(" + Hasil[0] + "deg)";
  element.classList.remove("animate");
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.add("animate");
  }, 5000);

  // Munculkan Alert
  setTimeout(function() {
    applause.play();
    swal(
      "Congratulations",
      "You Won The " + SelectedItem + ".",
      "success"
    );
  }, 5500);

  // Delay and set to normal state
  setTimeout(function() {
    box.style.setProperty("transition", "initial");
    box.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
  }, 6000);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url(https://source.unsplash.com/hNvr4nqFIcQ/2500x1800);
  background-size: cover;
}

.mainbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.mainbox::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://marsurl.com/images/VCiVd.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  top: 48%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #949090;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease-in-out 5s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.span1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 17%, 0 50%, 50% 50%);
  background-color: green;
}

.span2 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 17%, 30% 0, 50% 50%);
  background-color: red;
}

.span3 {
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 71% 0, 50% 50%);
  background-color: blue;
}

.span4 {
  clip-path: polygon(71% 0, 100% 18%, 50% 50%);
  background-color: salmon;
}

.span5 {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 18%, 100% 50%, 50% 50%);
  background: #ff8300;
}

.box2 .span3 {
  background-color: #00ff04;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.font {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.box1 .span1 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  right: 60%;
  transform: rotate(200deg);
  text-align: center;
}

.box1 .span2 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 57%;
  transform: rotate(-130deg);
}

.box1 .span3 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 36%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.box1 .span4 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 15%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.box1 .span5 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38%;
  right: 10%;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  text-align: center;
}

.box2 .span1 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  right: 70%;
  transform: rotate(200deg);
}

.box2 .span2 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 60%;
  transform: rotate(-130deg);
  text-align: center;
}

.box2 .span3 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 40%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.box2 .span4 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27%;
  right: 20%;
  transform: rotate(310deg);
}

.box2 .span5 b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  right: 10%;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  text-align: center;
}

.spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background-color: #ff5722;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.spin:active {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.mainbox.animate::after {
  animation: animateArrow 0.7s ease infinite;
}

audio {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes animateArrow {
  50% {
    right: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox" id="mainbox">
  <div class="box" id="box">
    <div class="box1">
      <span class="font span1"><b>Samsung Tab A6</b></span>
      <span class="font span2"><b>JBL Speaker</b></span>
      <span class="font span3"><b>Magic Roaster</b></span>
      <span class="font span4"><b>Sepeda Aviator</b></span>
      <span class="font span5"><b>Rice Cooker <br />Philips</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <span class="font span1"><b>Lunch Box Lock&Lock</b></span>
      <span class="font span2"><b>Air Cooler <br />Sanken</b></span>
      <span class="font span3"><b>Ipad Mini 4</b></span>
      <span class="font span4"><b>Exclusive Gift</b></span>
      <span class="font span5"><b>Electrolux <br />Blender</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="spin" onclick="spin()">SPIN</button>
</div>

<audio controls="controls" id="applause" src="./applause.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<audio controls="controls" id="wheel" src="./wheel.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```